# Can someone please explain what is a client in micro service architecture?

Tags: rest

Can someone please explain what is a client in micro service architecture? (Yes , I know it's a stupid question. I know it's used to talk to service but how does it work? No wiki links plz)

Comment: What did you understand from your search regarding this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client in a micro service architecture (which I had to look up) is like a client in any kind of service architecture. It's something that consumes a service.

Back in the day, there were phone numbers (still are as far as I can tell) that you could call that would give you the current time. "At the tone, the time will be 8:01 AM...*beep*".

That's a time service, the person making the phone call is the client.

The premise of MSA is basically composing your applications through the consumption of services. This is different from an OO application where you build your applications through extending and embedding other objects or classes.

In OO, a subclass is not a "client" per se of a super class, rather it's a specialization of the super class.

But if you utilize another service, large or small, you're a client of that service. You send your request, you get your result, with services being small bundles of related functionality.

Comment: but we can make request directly by POST /GET , why we need clients then for making requests?